# PowerBI DAX, calculate by a lookup in Dimension table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure of margin against seasonID in my fact table

I'm trying to do season on season comparison and the previous year's applicable seasonID is in the Season Dimension table

```
`LYAveStoreAveWeeklyMargin = CALCULATE(SUM('dwh030_Line'[StoreAveWeeklyMargin]),'dwh100_DimSeason'[LastYearSeasonID])`
```

but that just does the same as the current year

I have tried using FILTER and LOOKUPVALUE but I've been looking for two days now and i'm no nearer the answer

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Also, I'm not looking to do year on year, the way seasons compare isn't that straight forward, so I don't think a calendar table will help

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dH2d.png)

[line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGIZQ.png)

[season](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gOQ8.png)

Regards

Oliver

Comment: Please show your model and sample data that can be used to replicate your problem. There's too much guesswork left at the moment.

Comment: added after much fun with html, thanks

Comment: So you are creating a calculated column. I think you'd be better off with measures, but it always depends on you actual use case, which I don't know. So for the column to work, try changing `'dwh100_DimSeason'[LastYearSeasonID]` to `'dwh100_DimSeason'[SeasonID] = EARLIER('dwh100_DimSeason'[LastYearSeasonID])`

Comment: Most likely, you will have to do a bit more, but I can't check for sure atm, like `FILTER(ALL('dwh100_DimSeason'), 'dwh100_DimSeason'[SeasonID] = EARLIER('dwh100_DimSeason'[LastYearSeasonID] && [otherColumn] = EARLIER([otherColumn]))` within CALCULATE

Comment: Hi. Many thanks, lots to tinker with there. Firstly, yeah I really want a measure, good point. The first DAX there falls to "EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist.
Parameter is not the correct type.
Cannot find name '[LastYearSeasonID]"

Comment: I think I've got it working with a calculated field of...WhatsLastSeason = LOOKUPVALUE (
    'dwh100_DimSeason'[LastYearSeasonID],
    'dwh100_DimSeason'[SeasonID], 'dwh030_Line'[SeasonId]
) and then LYAveStoreAveWeeklyMargin =
VAR Rumpo = min('dwh030_Line'[WhatsLastSeason])
RETURN CALCULATE (
    SUM('dwh030_Line'[StoreAveWeeklyMargin]),
    FILTER ( ALL('dwh030_Line'[SeasonID]),'dwh030_Line'[SeasonID]=Rumpo)
)